Нужна ли запятая в этом предлoжении?
Ему не отказала(,) и мне не откажи.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в этом предложении и как правильно в данном случае определить грамматическую основу?

Правильно:
ЕмУ не отказала, и мнЕ не откажи.
Пояснение
Это ССП, сочинительный союз И.
Две предикативные основы. Первое предложение двусоставное неполное, подлежащее восстанавливается по контексту (ты ему не отказала). Второе предложение односоставное определенно-личное, сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме повелительного наклонения (2-е лицо, ед. число).
В предложениях один субъект действия, но разная грамматика. Поэтому это сложное предложение, а не простое. Оснований для отсутствия запятой нет, интонационный анализ также подтверждает наличие паузы и двух логических ударений на дополнениях ему и мне.
Полные и неполные предложения
Определенно-личные предложения
